# Pyspark SQL select data where a column is NaN

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I select only the rows where a certain column has `NaN` values in pyspark?

## Setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# pyspark
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext


spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('app').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sc.setLogLevel("INFO")


# data
dft = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Name': ['Odeon', 'Imperial', 'Majestic',
             'Royale', 'Paraiso', 'Nickelodeon'],
    'Movie': [5.0, 1.0, np.nan, 6.0, 3.0, np.nan]})


schema = StructType([
    StructField('Code',IntegerType(),True),
    StructField('Name',StringType(),True),
    StructField('Movie',FloatType(),True),

    ])

sdft = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dft, schema)
sdft.createOrReplaceTempView("MovieTheaters")
sdft.show()
```

## My Attempt

```py
spark.sql("""
select * from MovieTheaters where Movie is null
""").show()

+----+----+-----+
|Code|Name|Movie|
+----+----+-----+
+----+----+-----+
```

I am getting EMPTY output, how to solve the issue?

Expected output:

```
+----+-----------+-----+
|Code|       Name|Movie|
+----+-----------+-----+
|   3|   Majestic|  NaN|
|   6|Nickelodeon|  NaN|
+----+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: `null` and `NaN` are not the same thing. You can use the `isnan` function. Try this: `spark.sql("select * from MovieTheaters where isnan(Movie)").show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the `np.nan` values from your data frame, use the following code:

```
>>> spark.sql("""select * from MovieTheaters where Movie = 'NaN' """).show()
+----+-----------+-----+
|Code|       Name|Movie|
+----+-----------+-----+
|   3|   Majestic|  NaN|
|   6|Nickelodeon|  NaN|
+----+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: At first, I thought this was wrong (due to datatype mismatches) but surprisingly it works..?

Comment: @pault, I thought exactly the same way.

Comment: My guess is that spark makes an implicit conversion when comparing the different types so string `"NaN"` gets cast, resulting in float `NaN`